# Rhythmbox : browse by album art with Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, rhythmbox

This is an old recurring question, but it seems to me impossible to browse my music by covert art with latest Ubuntu 20.04 & rhythmbox 3.4.4 version. Looking either at the github page installation instructions (gir1.2-webkit-3.0 error) or the fossfreedom ppa (plugin does not exist), I am unable to install it.

Did I miss something ? Thanks for your answers.